# Troubleshooting Unbalanced Panel Error in R's Synth Package for Synthetic Control Method

Tags: r, r-package, synth

I'm working with a dataset named company_data_with_beta_2, containing quarterly firm-level data, including financial metrics and firm characteristics. My objective is to use the Synth package in R to create a synthetic control group for a treatment effect study. The dataset includes a Treatment_Control column indicating treated (1) and control (0) firms and a time column as a pre/post-treatment indicator (1 for post-treatment, 0 for pre-treatment).

**Predictors for Synthetic Control Group:**
"Firm_Size"
"Fixed_Assets_Ratio"
"Leverage"
"Revenue_Growth"

**Issue:**
When attempting to implement the Synthetic Control Method, I encounter an "unbalanced panel" error, stating: "Your panel, as described by unit.variable and time.variable, is unbalanced. Balance it and run again."

**Steps Taken:**

1. Created a subset of the dataset (cds) and omitted all NAs.

```
 cds <- subset(company_data_with_beta_2, select = c("gvkey", "firmid", "time", "datadate", "Days_Sales_Outstanding", "NAICS_3digits", "Firm_Size", "Fixed_Assets_Ratio", "Leverage", "Revenue_Growth","Treatment_Control"))
        # Remove rows with NA values in any column
        company_data_with_beta_2 <- na.omit(cds)
```

2. Ensured each firm (firmid) has data for all time periods, attempting to balance the panel.

```
 Create a table of firmid by time
        firm_time_count <- table(company_data_with_beta_2$firmid, company_data_with_beta_2$time)
        
        # Identify firmids that have data for all time periods
        complete_firmids <- rownames(firm_time_count)[apply(firm_time_count, 1, function(x) all(x > 0))]
        
        # Filter the dataset
        company_data_balanced <- company_data_with_beta_2[company_data_with_beta_2$firmid %in% complete_firmids, ]
        
        
        # Verify if the panel is balanced
        firm_time_table_balanced <- table(company_data_balanced$firmid, company_data_balanced$time)
        if(all(firm_time_table_balanced > 0)) {
          print("The panel is now balanced.")
        } else {
          print("The panel is still unbalanced.")
        }
```

Despite these steps, I continue to encounter the unbalanced panel error when executing the Synth package's dataprep function:

```
company_data_balanced <- as.data.frame(company_data_balanced)
    dataprep.out <- dataprep(
      foo = company_data_balanced,
      predictors = c("Firm_Size", "Fixed_Assets_Ratio", "Leverage", "Revenue_Growth"),
      predictors.op = "mean",
      dependent = "Days_Sales_Outstanding",
      unit.variable = "firmid",
      time.variable = "time",
      treatment.identifier = single_treated_unit,
      controls.identifier = control_units_n,
      time.predictors.prior = 0,
      time.optimize.ssr = 0,
      unit.names.variable = "gvkey",
      time.plot = c(0, 1)
    )
```

**Additional Context:**
For testing purposes, I used a single treated unit and multiple control units.

```
 # Get the list of gvkeys for treatment units
        treatment_units <- unique(company_data_balanced$gvkey[company_data_balanced$Treatment_Control == 1])
        treatment_units_n <- unique(company_data_balanced$firmid[company_data_balanced$Treatment_Control == 1])
        # Select a single treated unit for testing
        single_treated_unit <- treatment_units[1]
        
        # Get the list of gvkeys for control units
        control_units <- unique(company_data_balanced$gvkey[company_data_balanced$Treatment_Control == 0])
        control_units_n <- unique(company_data_balanced$firmid[company_data_balanced$Treatment_Control == 0])
```

And I saved the dataset as a dataframe, following other posts on issues of the Synth Package.

**Data Sample:**

Here's a look at the first few rows of my dataset:

Output from head(company_data_balanced)

```
head(company_data_balanced,n = 200)
   gvkey firmid time   datadate Days_Sales_Outstanding NAICS_3digits Firm_Size Fixed_Assets_Ratio Leverage Revenue_Growth Treatment_Control
1   1045   1045    0 2017-12-31                  60.27           481  9.269646               0.97     0.44          -0.03                 1
2   1045   1045    0 2018-03-31                  63.48           481  9.249657               0.95     0.41          -0.02                 1
3   1045   1045    0 2018-06-30                  60.85           481  9.362460               0.97     0.42           0.12                 1
4   1045   1045    0 2018-09-30                  68.52           481  9.355220               0.98     0.42          -0.01                 1
5   1045   1045    0 2018-12-31                  56.93           481  9.299998               1.00     0.48          -0.05                 1
6   1045   1045    0 2019-03-31                  64.70           481  9.267099               1.01     0.47          -0.03                 1
7   1045   1045    0 2019-06-30                  59.30           481  9.389323               1.00     0.48           0.13                 1
8   1045   1045    0 2019-09-30                  56.69           481  9.385218               1.01     0.48           0.00                 1
9   1045   1045    0 2019-12-31                  56.46           481  9.333708               1.04     0.48          -0.05                 1
10  1045   1045    1 2020-12-31                 121.61           481  8.301025               0.91     0.59          -0.64                 1
11  1045   1045    1 2021-03-31                  88.43           481  8.296048               0.81     0.64           0.00                 1
12  1045   1045    1 2021-09-30                  54.21           481  9.101529               0.81     0.62           1.24                 1
13  1045   1045    1 2021-12-31                  58.27           481  9.151333               0.84     0.63           0.05                 1
14  1045   1045    1 2022-03-31                  63.04           481  9.093694               0.83     0.62          -0.06                 1
15  1045   1045    1 2022-06-30                  49.90           481  9.504650               0.83     0.61           0.51                 1
16  1045   1045    1 2022-09-30                  53.98           481  9.507626               0.86     0.61           0.00                 1
17  1045   1045    1 2022-12-31                  59.17           481  9.487063               0.90     0.60          -0.02                 1
18  1045   1045    1 2023-03-31                  59.56           481  9.408289               0.88     0.57          -0.08                 1
19  1045   1045    1 2023-06-30                  53.83           481  9.550733               0.88     0.55           0.15                 1
20  1045   1045    1 2023-09-30                  54.71           481  9.509111               0.91     0.55          -0.04                 1
21  1050   1050    0 2017-12-31                 337.44           333  4.297870               0.10     0.25          -0.13                 1
22  1050   1050    0 2019-12-31                 279.36           333  4.493266               0.12     0.20           0.05                 1
23  1050   1050    1 2020-12-31                 277.48           333  4.417997               0.11     0.20           0.07                 1
24  1050   1050    1 2021-12-31                 292.47           333  4.538913               0.11     0.18           0.17                 1
25  1050   1050    1 2022-12-31                 260.53           333  4.757050               0.11     0.24           0.07                 1
26  1075   1075    0 2017-09-30                 130.32           221  7.076081               1.12     0.26           0.25                 0
27  1075   1075    0 2017-12-31                 145.41           221  6.632870               1.16     0.28          -0.36                 0
28  1075   1075    0 2018-03-31                 110.73           221  6.540617               1.14     0.25          -0.09                 0
29  1075   1075    0 2018-06-30                 118.89           221  6.881538               1.13     0.24           0.41                 0
30  1075   1075    0 2018-12-31                 127.31           221  6.628539               1.16     0.26          -0.22                 0
31  1075   1075    0 2019-03-31                 121.80           221  6.607366               1.14     0.28          -0.02                 0
32  1075   1075    0 2019-09-30                 108.71           221  7.082370               1.13     0.27           0.61                 0
33  1075   1075    0 2019-12-31                 140.61           221  6.507861               1.16     0.26          -0.44                 0
34  1075   1075    1 2020-06-30                 105.19           221  6.834744               1.14     0.33           0.39                 0
35  1075   1075    1 2020-09-30                 116.19           221  7.134493               1.12     0.34           0.35                 0
36  1075   1075    1 2020-12-31                 144.72           221  6.607948               1.14     0.33          -0.41                 0
37  1075   1075    1 2021-03-31                 127.20           221  6.546032               1.13     0.34          -0.06                 0
38  1075   1075    1 2021-06-30                 122.01           221  6.908004               1.10     0.33           0.44                 0
39  1075   1075    1 2021-09-30                 112.95           221  7.176449               1.09     0.34           0.31                 0
40  1075   1075    1 2022-03-31                 139.75           221  6.663811               1.10     0.36          -0.40                 0
41  1075   1075    1 2022-06-30                 136.54           221  6.967597               1.10     0.35           0.35                 0
42  1075   1075    1 2022-09-30                 143.83           221  7.292930               1.09     0.35           0.38                 0
43  1075   1075    1 2022-12-31                 155.30           221  6.917026               1.13     0.37          -0.31                 0
44  1075   1075    1 2023-06-30                 147.97           221  7.022603               1.11     0.39           0.11                 0
45  1075   1075    1 2023-09-30                 143.59           221  7.401084               1.10     0.38           0.46                 0
46  1078   1078    0 2017-09-30                 256.55           334  8.828934               0.20     0.32           0.03                 1
47  1078   1078    0 2017-12-31                 252.46           334  8.934455               0.20     0.36           0.11                 1
48  1078   1078    0 2018-06-30                 243.99           334  8.957639               0.22     0.29           0.02                 1
49  1078   1078    0 2018-09-30                 251.30           334  8.943245               0.22     0.27          -0.01                 1
50  1078   1078    0 2018-12-31                 243.58           334  8.957382               0.23     0.29           0.01                 1
51  1078   1078    0 2019-03-31                 258.92           334  8.927314               0.25     0.29          -0.03                 1
52  1078   1078    0 2019-06-30                 253.79           334  8.984568               0.25     0.29           0.06                 1
53  1078   1078    0 2019-09-30                 246.32           334  8.996652               0.25     0.27           0.01                 1
54  1078   1078    0 2019-12-31                 238.17           334  9.025696               0.26     0.26           0.03                 1
55  1078   1078    0 2020-03-31                 250.01           334  8.952347               0.25     0.25          -0.07                 1
56  1078   1078    1 2020-09-30                 232.90           334  9.088512               0.26     0.27           0.15                 1
57  1078   1078    1 2020-12-31                 218.77           334  9.278092               0.27     0.27           0.21                 1
58  1078   1078    1 2021-03-31                 212.80           334  9.254931               0.26     0.24          -0.02                 1
59  1078   1078    1 2021-06-30                 218.26           334  9.232395               0.26     0.24          -0.02                 1
60  1078   1078    1 2021-09-30                 213.93           334  9.299084               0.26     0.24           0.07                 1
61  1078   1078    1 2022-03-31                 220.29           334  9.383873               0.26     0.23           0.09                 1
62  1078   1078    1 2022-06-30                 233.42           334  9.328745               0.26     0.22          -0.05                 1
63  1078   1078    1 2022-09-30                 224.68           334  9.250522               0.27     0.21          -0.08                 1
64  1078   1078    1 2023-03-31                 225.43           334  9.184715               0.28     0.20          -0.06                 1
65  1078   1078    1 2023-06-30                 225.77           334  9.208138               0.29     0.19           0.02                 1
66  1078   1078    1 2023-09-30                 233.87           334  9.224539               0.29     0.20           0.02                 1
67  1117   1117    0 2017-12-31                 213.99           334  2.243047               0.22     0.00          -0.20                 1
68  1117   1117    0 2018-12-31                 195.59           334  2.367998               0.27     0.00          -0.20                 1
69  1117   1117    0 2019-12-31                 196.66           334  1.995652               0.42     0.08          -0.45                 1
70  1117   1117    1 2020-12-31                 223.64           334  2.356410               0.42     0.08           0.06                 1
71  1117   1117    1 2021-12-31                 233.96           334  2.552410               0.34     0.06           0.02                 1
72  1161   1161    0 2017-06-30                 194.71           334  7.048386               0.28     0.41          -0.02                 1
73  1161   1161    0 2017-09-30                 177.66           334  7.367709               0.27     0.38           0.38                 1
74  1161   1161    0 2018-03-31                 163.55           334  7.406711               0.26     0.31           0.04                 1
75  1161   1161    0 2018-09-30                 266.52           334  7.410347               0.24     0.27           0.00                 1
76  1161   1161    0 2019-06-30                 317.80           334  7.333676               0.28     0.24          -0.07                 1
77  1161   1161    0 2019-09-30                 282.31           334  7.496097               0.27     0.20           0.18                 1
78  1161   1161    0 2019-12-31                 322.44           334  7.662468               0.24     0.11           0.18                 1
79  1161   1161    0 2020-03-31                 349.06           334  7.487734               0.27     0.12          -0.16                 1
80  1161   1161    1 2020-06-30                 339.87           334  7.566311               0.25     0.11           0.08                 1
81  1161   1161    1 2020-09-30                 278.60           334  7.937732               0.24     0.08           0.45                 1
82  1161   1161    1 2021-03-31                 231.50           334  8.144679               0.19     0.05           0.23                 1
83  1161   1161    1 2021-06-30                 192.08           334  8.255828               0.18     0.05           0.12                 1
84  1161   1161    1 2021-09-30                 188.64           334  8.369389               0.18     0.02           0.12                 1
85  1161   1161    1 2021-12-31                 204.81           334  8.481773               0.18     0.03           0.12                 1
86  1161   1161    1 2022-03-31                 228.23           334  8.680502               0.04     0.03           0.22                 1
87  1161   1161    1 2022-06-30                 225.85           334  8.787220               0.05     0.04           0.11                 1
88  1161   1161    1 2022-09-30                 284.65           334  8.624252               0.05     0.04          -0.15                 1
89  1161   1161    1 2022-12-31                 269.11           334  8.630343               0.05     0.04           0.01                 1
90  1161   1161    1 2023-03-31                 275.61           334  8.585412               0.05     0.04          -0.04                 1
```

And the structure, in case it helps:

```
str(company_data_balanced)
'data.frame':   10853 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ gvkey                 : chr  "1045" "1045" "1045" "1045" ...
 $ firmid                : num  1045 1045 1045 1045 1045 ...
 $ time                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ datadate              : chr  "2017-12-31" "2018-03-31" "2018-06-30" "2018-09-30" ...
 $ Days_Sales_Outstanding: num  60.3 63.5 60.9 68.5 56.9 ...
 $ NAICS_3digits         : chr  "481" "481" "481" "481" ...
 $ Firm_Size             : num  9.27 9.25 9.36 9.36 9.3 ...
 $ Fixed_Assets_Ratio    : num  0.97 0.95 0.97 0.98 1 1.01 1 1.01 1.04 0.91 ...
 $ Leverage              : num  0.44 0.41 0.42 0.42 0.48 0.47 0.48 0.48 0.48 0.59 ...
 $ Revenue_Growth        : num  -0.03 -0.02 0.12 -0.01 -0.05 -0.03 0.13 0 -0.05 -0.64 ...
 $ Treatment_Control     : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int [1:5905] 1 22 23 24 26 27 28 29 30 31 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5905] "1" "22" "23" "24" ...
```